# How to insert an image on all pages using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to insert an image on every page.

I know that the command is Next in a For loop.

```vb
Sub InsertImage()
Dim oILS As InlineShape, oShp As Shape
Set oILS = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:= _
  "C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\Desktop\SubEscritorio3\Ejercicios Matemáticas\Barra.png", LinkToFile:=False, _
  SaveWithDocument:=True)
Set oShp = oILS.ConvertToShape
With oShp
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
    .Left = -55
    .Top = 471.1
    .Height = 21.5
    .Width = 522
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the same image to appear on all pages, you should put it in either the header or footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the way to do it on all pages. If it helps anyone, here it is:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, Shp As Shape, ImageName As String
ImageName = "C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\Desktop\SubEscritorio3\Ejercicios Matemáticas\Barra.png"
With ActiveDocument
Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
For i = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
Set Shp = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=ImageName, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=Rng).ConvertToShape
With Shp
.Left = -55
.Top = 471.1
.Width = 522
.Height = 21.5
.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind

End With
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your code is working and solve your problem, please accept your own answer as an answer. This will help others when searching for similar questions to pick up yours, because searchers always try to llok for questions that already have answers.